# Unpacking a Python generator into arguments - memory efficient?

Tags: python, python-2.7, iterator, generator

Say I have a generator for `sets`:

```
def f(n) :
  for i in xrange(n) :
    yield set(xrange(i) )

>>> for s in f(5) :
      print s

set([])
set([0])
set([0, 1])
set([0, 1, 2])
set([0, 1, 2, 3])
```

Now I want to `union` them. I can create a temporary list of sets, and unpack that list into arguments for `union`:

```
>>> set.union( * list( f(5) ) )
set([0, 1, 2, 3])
```

I can also give the generator itself to `union`:

```
>>> set.union( * f(5) )
set([0, 1, 2, 3])
```

Does the second approach create the full temporary list like the first one? Which approach is memory efficient?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Python expands a generator *first* when applying it as arguments; all values produced by the generator are loaded into memory before the call takes place, in both options.

You could use a [`reduce()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) call instead:

```
from functools import reduce  # Python 3 forward compatibility

reduce(set.union, f(5))
```

This iterates over the values produced by `f(5)` one by one without building up a sequence of them first.

Demo:

```
>>> def f(n):
...     for i in xrange(n):
...         yield set(xrange(i))
... 
>>> reduce(set.union, f(5))
set([0, 1, 2, 3])
```

Answer (score 4):

Both approaches will evaluate (and store) all the elements of the generator.  When calling a function, the entire argument list must be evaluated before the function is called.

You can see this with a little example:

```
def f(n):
    for i in xrange(n) :
        yield set(xrange(i) )
    1/0

def blah(*args):
    print "Blah!"

>>> blah(*f(5))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#56>", line 1, in <module>
    blah(*f(5))
  File "<pyshell#52>", line 4, in f
    1/0
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Notice that "Blah!" is not printed.  Since an exception is raised while trying to evaluate all the elements in the generator `f(5)`, the call to `blah` never takes place.