# merge multiple sorted big files--python

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, merge, mergesort

The task is to merge sort two big files (cannot fit in the memory). After doing a little bit research, it seems that it's pretty easy to do it using `heapq.merge`

```
import heapq
import contextlib

filenames=('data1.txt', 'data2.txt')
with contextlib.ExitStack() as stack:
    files = [stack.enter_context(open(fn)) for fn in filenames]
    with open('data', 'w') as f:
        f.writelines(heapq.merge(*files))
```

The problem is that how to handle the empty lines in the files. For example:

> Data1.txt:
>
> apple
>
> amazon
>
> google
>
> Data2.txt:
>
> hello
>
> today
>
> world

```
Output:

apple 
amazon 
google 
hello 
today 
world
```

My answer for not using heapq.merge:

```
def read_non_empty_line(input):
    while True:
        line = input.readline()
        if line == "":
            return ""
        if line.isspace() == False:
            return line.strip()
    #return line

def combine_sorted_files(file1, file2, output):

    read_file1, read_file2 = True, True

    with open(output,'w') as output_file:
        with open(file1,'r') as input_file1:
            with open(file2,'r') as input_file2:
                while True:
                    if read_file1:
                        line1 = read_non_empty_line(input_file1)
                    if read_file2:
                        line2 = read_non_empty_line(input_file2)

                    if line1 == "" or line2 == "":
                        break

                    read_file1, read_file2 = False, False
                    if line1 < line2:
                        smaller = line1
                        read_file1 = True
                    else:
                        smaller = line2
                        read_file2 = True

                    output_file.write(smaller+"\n\n")

                while line1 != "":
                    output_file.write(line1+"\n\n")
                    line1 = read_non_empty_line(input_file1)
                while line2 != "":
                    output_file.write(line2+"\n\n")
                    line2 = read_non_empty_line(input_file2)
```

This problem also requests to optimize both memory and CPU utilization. Are there any suggestions?

Comment: `heapq.merge` only works with sorted input data. Are your data files already sorted?

Comment: @SamuelO'Malley yeah!

Comment: Is this a homework question? If so I would highly recommend trying to implement this yourself without `heapq.merge` because its not very difficult and will make it quite easy to skip blank lines.

Comment: @SamuelO'Malley, got it. I'll implement it without the heaq.merge and then post it. After that, can you answer this question? I'm also pretty interested in doing it with heaq.merge.

Comment: I'll give an answer for heapq.merge then, please let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: @SamuelO'Malley, I've updated with my answer without heapq.merge. Can you help me check it and also give me some suggestions how to optimize the CPU and memory utilization

Comment: Does it run and work?

Comment: It looks a bit overly complicated to me. You need to read the first line of each file, and if one is blank read the next line of that file. Once both are non-blank, write out the smaller line to the output file and then read the next line for that file. Repeat this until you hit the end of both files.

Comment: Does `*files` not unpack the data into memory, thereby negating the benefit of using a generator? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25345676/unpacking-a-python-generator-into-arguments-memory-efficient.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use `heapq.merge` while skipping blank lines, you can create your own generator function to handle the skip logic:

```
def iterate_non_blank_lines(file_iterator):
    for line in file_iterator:
        if line != "":
            yield line
```

Note: I have simply checked for blank lines, but you could easily use a regular expression here to skip lines that contain only whitespace for example.

Then your code could be modified to use this generator:

```
filenames=('data1.txt', 'data2.txt')
with contextlib.ExitStack() as stack:
    files = [iterate_non_blank_lines(stack.enter_context(open(fn))) for fn in filenames]
    with open('data', 'w') as f:
        f.writelines(heapq.merge(*files))
```

Also, this question sounds a lot like a homework problem (appologies if it's not) and I would highly recommend implementing the merge logic yourself because it is a fun problem.

Comment: Thanks so much! Yeah, it's fun to implement the merge logic. I'm doing it. :-)